# Background Threads in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am new to C#.I learnt that normally all threads are foreground until unless you explicitly specify it as "background" thread using  *IsBackGround= true*  .

Some doubts popped in to my mind.

1) What is the advantage of keeping a thread as background thread?

2) When  executing  the folowing code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(SayHello);
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello From Main");
    }

    static void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

i need to use worker.Join() to keep the main thread to wait as the program terminates immediately. Apart from Join() could i use other techniques to keep the main thread wait ?

Comment: threading in C# is quite an interesting thing.  I highly recommend the ClR via C# book from Jeffrey Richter.  He has an explanation from the windows kernel up of how threads work in C#.  Unfortunately many of these concepts fall back onto C++ Win32 threading api.

Comment: Your going to have more fun with the thread synchronisation stuff.  Have a look at the System.Threading.Semaphore, ManualResetEvent, AutoResetEvent, Mutex and Interlocked classes.  THey're all very useful for doing threading stuff.

Comment: Thank Spence Thank you very much.I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1) What is the advantage of keeping a
>   thread as background thread?

The Advantage is that a Background Thread doesn't stop the Program from terminating. In a large Application it could be a bit hard to deactivate all threads if you want to quit the Application.

> Apart from Join() could i use other techniques to keep the main thread wait?

If yo want to make the Main program wait why do you make the thread a background thread in the first place then???
Besides of Join() you could use a EventWaitHandle or Monitor to make the main method wait.

Answer (score 6):

All it means is whether this thread will keep the process alive.  If all the threads in your process are marked background then .Net will shut down your process and force it to exit.

In answer to your question, yes you have to join as the thread which is in the background will not keep it alive, thus when the startup thread leaves Main() then it will allow the application to exit.

Answer (score 3):

If the thread should complete before the program terminates, then it should not be a background thread.

There are lots of ways to make your main thread wait, but in the example above I think what you really want to do is to make sure it's not a background thread.

The Join method is generally used to make sure that threads are done executing before the calling thread continues. For example, you may spawn 5 threads that each do some math operation and the results of those operations may be needed to move on with the next step. The Join method will pause execution on the calling thread until the spawned threads can completed. It is important to note that if you call Join from the UI thread you will freeze your program until the spawned threads are finished.

In short, multi threading is really complicated and nuanced. I highly recommend buying a good book on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AutoResetEvent to make a method wait,

```
static AutoResetEvent obj = new AutoResetEvent();
```

Then from the main function

```
new Thread(SayHello).Start();
//Signal to start
obj.Set();
```

Inside SayHello

```
// wait
obj.WaitOne();
```

In this scenario you can skip worker.IsBackground = true;