# Function call in c#

Tags: c#

call a function continuously in c# console application. without using infinite loop and recursion because if use those then cpu usage is more.please can any one help me to solve this problem.some one suggest me to use background thread, but it doesn't call the function continuously.

```
Thread th = new Thread(//fun);
th.IsBackground = true;
th.start();
```

Comment: To not use a lot of cpu you don't want to call in continously, you want to call it periodically. Which means introducing a waiting period between each call.

Comment: A relates question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550303/background-threads-in-c-sharp. As you can see you must use th.Start() and using that under static function, for example main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a system timer with a short interval.

In the "tick" event of the timer:

- Stop the timer
- Call the function
- Restart the timer

A system timer's event runs on a thread pool thread so your console app thread continues as normal. The function is run as frequently as the interval allows, for the duration of the application. No recursion. No infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call it continuously, then a high CPU usage is necessary: because the CPU is always busy doing what you want.

If you want to have a lower cpu usage, then you **cannot** run your function continuously but only  at a (possibly very small) interval.

You have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Thread code but a thread just effectively calls the function which means that your function needs to be recursive or that it needs to have an infinite loop.

```
public void StartThread()
{
   Thread th = new Thread(function);
   th.IsBackground = true;
   th.start();
}

public void function()
{    
   //preferably have some way of killing this if needs be so don't necessarily use 'true'
   while(true)
   {
      //do stuff

      //sleep an appropriate amount of time to not overload the cpu
      //This sleeps (basically pauses thread) for 10 milliseconds
      Thread.Sleep(10);
   }
}
```

Adding the Thread.Sleep will stop the overloading of the CPU which you were referring to. Just run sleep for an amount of time which is acceptable for your application. If it's updating a value on a GUI then the user won't really notice if the value gets updated every half second (Thread.Sleep(500)) or every milliseconds (Thread.Sleep(1))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your answer, but let me explain how a thread works.

---

**Threads**

Threading, in most programming languages, is the practice of effectively splitting up execution, into synchronous execution. What this means, is that two methods can run at the same time.

**Common uses of a Thread**

One example of the use of a thread, is to listen for incoming connections on a server. So you'd have a thread, something like:

```
while(true)
{
    // Listen to incoming messages.
}
```

The infinite loop is because, at no point, do you want to stop listening for incoming messages. That is the role of the server; to manage connections. However, the thread is killed when the program execution finishes. The reason why this is considered common practice is, because of the fact that this is run on a separate thread, it doesn't impact performance as much as you might think. C# is very good at dealing with multiple threads; as are most languages.

**Alternatives**

Well, look at it like this. If you want to listen for 1000 cycles, then you will do something like:

```
while(count < 1000)
{
     count++;
     // Do some thread code.
}
```

It really depends on what you want the thread for, that defines the code that goes into the thread, and how long it will run for.